# C++ Poco - How to iterate thought a JSON array?

Tags: c++, arrays, poco-libraries

I've seen some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044184/poco-iterating-nested-json-objects) how to iterate thought nested `JSON` objects like:

```
 "{ \"test\" : { \"property\" : \"value\" } }"
```

But now I need to iterate through a `JSON` array (the *children* `array` below):

```
"{ \"name\" : \"Franky\", \"children\" : [ \"Jonas\", \"Ellen\" ] }"
```

How can I achieve this?

I can't see anywhere an example or even on the `POCO` documentation.

I have this sample below, but can't get the array of *children*.

```
Poco::Dynamic::Var test = object->get("children");

Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr subObject = test.extract<Poco::JSON::Array::Ptr>();

for (it = subObject->begin(); it != subObject->end(); it++) // how to iterate here?
{
    std::cout << "my children:" << it->first << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want children's names in std::vector<std::string> maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods `begin` and `end` of your `subObject` array return `JSON::Array::ConstIterator` which is defined as follows

```
typedef std::vector<Dynamic::Var>::const_iterator ConstIterator;
```

so you can write

```
for (Poco::JSON::Array::ConstIterator it= subObject->begin(); it != subObject->end(); ++it)
{
  // do sth here
}
```

and when you know that `it` points to `Dynamic::Var` you can use `convert` or `extract` method to get string object:

```
for (Poco::JSON::Array::ConstIterator it = subObject->begin(); it != subObject->end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "my children:" << it->convert<std::string>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what I needed :)